# Upgrade from 18.04 to 20.04 failed with error in cache.update

Tags: upgrade, updates

I tried to upgrade from 18.04 LTS to 20.04 LTS but the upgrade failed producing:

```
ERROR IOError/SystemError in cache.update(): ''. Retrying (currentRetry: 0)
ERROR IOError/SystemError in cache.update(): ''. Retrying (currentRetry: 1)
ERROR IOError/SystemError in cache.update(): ''. Retrying (currentRetry: 2)
ERROR doUpdate() failed completely
```

The strange thing is the actual error (like unable to fetch something...) is not stated (the quotes are empty).
Any idea please what I should check or what info I should provide to make the problem clearer?

Answer (score 0):

1. I would check if you are properly connected to the internet first.
2. Do a `sudo apt update` followed by `sudo apt upgrade` and then `sudo do-release-upgrade -d`

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same issue when attempting to upgrade from 22.04.1 LTS to 22.10. The culprit ended up being errors in `sudo apt update`.

1. Run `sudo apt update`.
2. Resolve any errors listed there.
3. Repeat steps 1 and 2 until no more errors appear.

Then retrying the upgrade should be successful.